Play amazon firestick on linux laptop
I would like to be able to watch amazon firestick on my linux ubuntu laptop (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) instead of on a TV screen. Is that possible? I would prefer not to use an emulator as they can be very glitchy. I have seen this youtube video which shows a method for pc/mac using a video capture card and OBS. Does anyone have experience with trying this on linux?
Thanks all in advance.
Bioinfguru

It would be up to the maker of the device to make such software. I suggest you ask them.

If you have a capture card supported by Linux it will work.

Thank you. Looks like this might take a bit of efffort. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0iqvdpboAg
